# ClassCastException occuring while retrieving data from intent extras

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization

In an android app I trying to send a serializable object array to an activity from a fragment. But when I deserializing in activity it constantly shows class cast exception.

Here is the code of pager adapter where on image view click trying to open a activity.

```
public class ItemImageSliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context _context;
    Images[] images;

    public ItemImageSliderAdapter(Context _context, Images[] images) {
        this._context = _context;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(_context);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        Picasso.with(_context).load(images[position].getMain()).into(imageView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (images != null) {
                    fullImageSlider(v, images);
                }
            }
        });
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((ImageView) arg1);
    }

    public void fullImageSlider(View v, Images[] imageArray) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FullScreenImageSlider.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("data",imageArray);
        bundle.putString("flag", "hello");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

here is the code of activity where I am trying to get deserialized data from fragment

```
public class FullScreenImageSlider extends Activity {

    Images[] images = null;
    String flag;

    SmartViewPager slidePager;
    CirclePageIndicator pageIndicator;
    ItemImageSliderAdapter slideAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("data") != null) {
            flag = getIntent().getExtras().getString("flag");
            try {
                images = (Images[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(
                        "data");
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                Log.d("ex", "class cast exception");
            }
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.full_screen_slider);
        Log.d("flag", flag);
        findViews();
    }

    private void findViews() {
        slidePager = (SmartViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_slider);
        pageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.dots);
        /*
         * slideAdapter = new ItemImageSliderAdapter(this, images);
         * slidePager.setAdapter(slideAdapter);
         * pageIndicator.setViewPager(slidePager);
         */
    }

}
```

Here is the code of the model class I am using to serialize.

```
public class Images implements Serializable{
    private String id;

    private String isdefault;

    private String thumb;

    private String main;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIsdefault() {
        return isdefault;
    }

    public void setIsdefault(String isdefault) {
        this.isdefault = isdefault;
    }

    public String getThumb() {
        return thumb;
    }

    public void setThumb(String thumb) {
        this.thumb = thumb;
    }

    public String getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(String main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [id = " + id + ", isdefault = " + isdefault
                + ", thumb = " + thumb + ", main = " + main + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `_context`  variable to start intent

```
public void fullImageSlider(View v, Images[] imageArray) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(_context.getActivity(), FullScreenImageSlider.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("data",imageArray);
        bundle.putString("flag", "hello");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        _context.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: I already tried that. Even with that I got same error. I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: now try this Fragment returns its Activty using getActivity() method,try using `_context.getActivity()` or just `getActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving ClassCastException cause you object from extras is not `Serializable` (it is `Serializable[]`) while you are trying to get it with `getSerializable` method.
You should use `Parcelable` instead of `Serializable` for `Images`. Then you can just use `bundle.putParcelableArray(key, array);` to pass your data over intent.

Answer (score 0):

please check your import class of Images may be if you using android.provider.MediaStore.Images instead of your class